# Why iron reacts differently with concentrated and dilute sulfuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, solutions

When $\ce{H2SO4}$ is dilute,

> $ \ce{Fe +H2SO4 -> FeSO4 + H2} $

and when $\ce{H2SO4}$ is concentrated,

> $\ce{3Fe +8H2SO4 -> FeSO4 + Fe2(SO4)3 + 4SO2 +8H2O}$

What made the reaction with dilute acid different from the reaction with concentrated acid?

How did the second equation form, and why there are 2 salts - one with Fe[II] and the other with Fe[III]?

Comment: Well, the second equation has the formation of $\ce{SO2}$. How do you think this came about?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15612/what-will-happen-when-a-metal-reacts-with-an-acid-which-is-neither-dilute-nor-co  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19897/why-concentrated-sulfuric-acid-for-dehydration-and-dilute-for-hydration

Comment: @orthocresol i don't know

Comment: Also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28001/why-do-exam-questions-specify-dilute-acid

Comment: @bigworld12 You should add your thoughts about that, do you understand what happens in first equation?

Comment: @Mithoron i fully understand the first equation as i have been studying it for a long time , the (Fe) is more powerful than the (H) so it takes its place to provide a salt (FeSO4)

Comment: @bigworld12 Okay.. think about the oxidation states of S in H2SO4 and SO2. What has happened to sulfur?

Comment: @orthocresol it got reduced?

Comment: reduced from +7 to +4

Comment: @bigworld12 Yeah. Actually it's +6 to +4 but close enough. I'll type up an answer. Hold on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first equation, $\ce{Fe}$ is oxidised to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ by $\ce{H+}$; the $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ions play no role in the reaction. You could replace $\ce{H2SO4}$ with $\ce{HCl}$ and get the same reaction.

In the second equation, the same oxidation of $\ce{Fe}$ to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ by $\ce{H+}$ also occurs. However, *on top of that*, some of the $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ions are reduced to $\ce{SO2}$, and some of the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is further oxidised to $\ce{Fe^3+}$. Clearly, in the dilute acid, $\ce{SO4^2-}$ was not strong enough to act as an oxidising agent - but in the concentrated acid it is.

---

The reason for this can be somewhat explained by Le Chatelier's principle. Consider the redox reaction:

$$\ce{2Fe^2+ + SO4^2- + 4H+ -> 2Fe^3+ + SO2 + 2H2O}$$

In the dilute acid, this equilibrium lies far to the left because the concentrations of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ and $\ce{H+}$ are rather low. However, making the acid more concentrated shifts the equilibrium to the right so that you get some of the products.

As to why you get a mixture of iron(II) and iron(III), the simple answer is that the equilibrium above doesn't lie *entirely* to the right. $\ce{H2SO4}$ is not that strong an oxidising agent to begin with.

---

More quantitatively, the redox reaction above can be investigated using standard reduction potentials and the Nernst equation. The following data is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) (you will get pretty similar values from more "reliable" sources):

- $E^\circ(\ce{Fe^3+}/\ce{Fe^2+}) = +0.77 \mathrm{~V}$
- $E^\circ(\ce{SO4^2-}/\ce{SO2}) = +0.17 \mathrm{~V}$

Under standard conditions, $E^\circ$ for the full reaction is therefore $0.17-0.77 = -0.60 \mathrm{~V}$; the negative value indicates that the forward reaction is non-spontaneous.

The Nernst equation for this reaction can be written:

$$E = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q = E^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln\left[\frac{(a_{\ce{Fe^3+}})^2(a_{\ce{SO2}})(a_{\ce{H2O}})^2}{(a_{\ce{Fe^2+}})^2(a_{\ce{SO4^2-}})(a_{\ce{H+}})^4}\right]$$

I will make several assumptions here:

- Activity coefficients are taken to be unity, meaning that the activities can be replaced by concentrations.
- The activities of all the products, as well as $\ce{Fe^2+}$, are unity.
- The only source of $\ce{H+}$ is from the dissociation of the $\ce{H2SO4}$, and the dissociation is complete. That means that if $c$ is the formal concentration of $\ce{H2SO4}$, we have $[\ce{H+}] = 2c$ and $[\ce{SO4^2-}] = c$.

Substituting in the values of $E^\circ = -0.60 \mathrm{~V}$, $R = 8.314 \mathrm{~J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}$, $T = 298 \mathrm{~K}$, $n = 2$, and $F = 96485 \mathrm{~C~mol^{-1}}$, this allows us to simplify the Nernst equation:

$$E / \mathrm{V} = -0.60 + 0.0128\ln (16c^5)$$

Strictly speaking, I should use $c/c^\circ$ instead of $c$ in order to make the logarithm dimensionless, but I'm fed up of technicalities. Now for the actual calculation. Let's assume that you're using $10\mathrm{~M}$ sulfuric acid, such that $c = 10$ (or $c/c^\circ = 10$, if you want to insist). This gives a value of $E = -0.42 \mathrm{~V}$ - as expected, it is less negative than before, which corresponds to a larger value of $K = \exp(nFE/RT)$. The fact that it is still rather negative just means that there is a difference between the real world and my theoretical treatment. Presumably, those assumptions above are not entirely valid.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to be accurate in concepts:

Concentrated sulfuric acid is at least $18~\mathrm{M}$ and contains only 2% water by mass. In this situation, most sulfuric acid molecules do not ionize due to the lack of water. The oxidizing power of concentrated $\ce{H2SO4(l)}$ does not come from $\ce{H+}$ ions or $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ions, but rather the $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecules.

Comment: [Oh, so that's what one other question was dedicated to](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51140/weird-wikipedia-section-on-oxidizing-acids). It'd be great to have a reference confirming that H2SO4 molecules are the key players in concentrated sulfuric acid.

Answer (score 0):

Iron (also steel) is passive in concentrated H2SO4, forming a layer of sulfate on the surface.

Comment: And in dilute? The questions is on the difference between them.