# Why is diluted sulfuric acid more corrosive than concentrated sulfuric acid?

Tags: redox

It is said diluted sulfuric acid can't be stored in iron tank because it is more corrosive than concentrated sulfuric acid. I know there is a oxidation film will be formed for the concentrated sulfuric acid one. So, why doesn't diluted sulfuric acid have a film as well, is it because of the difference concentration of H ions?

Comment: It has been answered here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38822/why-iron-reacts-differently-with-concentrated-and-dilute-sulfuric-acid